# C# граница TabControl и Panel

Tags: c#

Имеется проблема с визуализацией в MetroUI. Если в MetroTabControl создать MetroPanel, и в параметре Dock поставить заполнение, то появляются такие полоски. При нажатии на них, они исчезают. Можно как-нибудь избавиться от них вообще? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После того как они исчезают они заново появляются?

Comment: Нет, только при запуске